$\frac{|g_{mn}| }{ |J(c\to x) |^2}$ invariant under coordinate transformation?
I'm wondering whether the term $\frac{|g_{mn}|}{|J(c\to x)|^2}$ is invariant under coordinate transformations.
Therein, $|g_{mn}| = \det(g_{mn})$ is the determinant of the metric tensor.
$|J(c\to x)|$ is the determinant of the Jacobian matrix of the transformation of Minkowski space from Cartesian to the used coordinates $x$.
I think it should be invariant because of the short proof below.
I use the fact that the determinant of the metric tensor transforms as a tensor density of weight 2:
$$ |g_{mn}(x')| = |J(x\to x')|^2 \cdot |g_{mn}(x)|, $$
that the consecutive application of two transformations are represented by the product of the respective transformation matrices:
$$ J(c\to x') = J(c\to x) \cdot J(x\to x'), $$
and that the determinant of a product is the product of the determinants.
Proof:
$$\begin{align}\frac{|g_{mn}(x')|}{|J(c\to x')|^2}
&=\frac {|J(x\to x')|^2 \cdot |g_{mn}(x)|}{|J(c\to x')|^2}\\
&=\frac {|J(x\to x')|^2 \cdot |g_{mn}(x)|}{|J(c\to x)J(x\to x')|^2}\\
&=\frac {|J(x\to x')|^2 \cdot |g_{mn}(x)|}{|J(c\to x)|^2 |J(x\to x') |^2}\\
&=\frac{|g_{mn}(x)|}{|J(c\to x)|^2}\end{align}$$
q. e. d.
Is this reasoning right or wrong? And if wrong, why?

Hi, welcome to Math SE. Thanks for your MathJax effort. It needed some dollar signs etc., so I've fixed it for you. Please double-check my interpretation of your fractions; a/b c is always tricky if you don't use proper formatting, as it might mean $\frac{a}{bc}$ or $\frac{a}{b}c$.

Thank you very much! Yes, everything 's fine.

Remark: The fact that this construction is a scalar seems to be true - but there's something wrong with the "proof". I don't know why that's the case, but I would be very interested in more explanation.
